# Android: NavigationDrawer vs. Tabbed Bar

Tags: android, android-tabhost, navigation-drawer

I'm developing an android app and i want to ask from a user-friendly perspective:

Using `NavigationDrawer`

or

Using Tabbed View (TabHost i think)

Which one is more user-friendly.

**Note:** I'm not an android user.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the amount of the categories you have.
If you have many categories with same level I prefer to Tabbed View.
If you want to compile many categories with different level, such as login, some selection, settings , I would rather use NavigationDrawer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to put in them, if you have more than three items (like categories) i'll use `NavigationDrawer` if you don't need more than three then use tabs.

It's a design concept.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)'s google official documentation on `NavigationDrawer`

Comment: I would also like to add a link that might help as well.  http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage  go to usages and it will explain when you should use the tabs.